# ALPS touchpad stops working after reboot

Tags: touchpad

I recently upgraded to 12.04 LTS. My Compaq Presario CQ-40 324la touchpad worked after first restarting after installation. But after restarting a second time, the touchpad is completely disabled, without having changed anything in the system.

I've tried solutions but haven't had good results. The applications I've installed (fro "solutions" are:

- Pointing Devices
- Synaptiks
- Dconf-Tools

I've also tried updating GRUB, adding this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nomux")
```

I tried these commands in a terminal. Neither has worked.

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I sometimes face similar problem. Generally running the Synaptiks application once or twice fixes my problem. You can open the dashboard by pressing the Super key and then search for application and select it using arrow keys and run it by hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

I had somewhat the same problem. My touchpad is an Alps multitouch ( Acer Aspire 7741G ).
 Sometimes, either after removing usb mouse or after resuming from suspend (can't figure out exactly which one, but I think one of these 2), my touchpad would stop working.
  I tried most advices (psmouse, xinput, etc), none worked.
  Logging out would make the touchpad work, but only for the login screen, after logging in, it would stop again. Reboot did not help either, same as log out.

while contemplating reinstalling Ubuntu, I tried logging in with the guest account. The mouse worked after login! So I started wondering if somehow my account settings (kept in the .xxx dirs/files in your home dir - you can see them with "ls -a" command, like `.config`) were at fault. So i did a backup of all my hidden dirs/files, and deleted them all (at login, if they are missing, they will be recreated, and you will have the desktop you had after installing).

And it worked! I didn't figure out exactly where the wrong settings were, but I suspect that it is something like `.config/unity`. If you don't want to lose all your settings (browser, transmission, unity, etc), you can try making a backup and deleting sequentially until you find the source, after that restore the ones that had nothing to do with the problem. I had no patience and deleted them all and had to redo all settings (too lazy to copy from backup).

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on Acer Aspire S3-391. It has been working fine. A few days ago after update touchpad stopped working. I checked `dconf-tools` setings for mouse it was fine and nothing else helped.
Then I installed `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and after the reboot it started working.

thanks
with regards
Vig

Comment: This is not really an answer. More of an anecdote. Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.